# Can I create web socket using Rails to connect to other website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, sockets, communication

I have existing rails website and I would like to create socket connection between my website and another one, so that my website can receive requests, and my website can send data using the socket connection(real-time).

**The Question**: Is that possible in rails or should I use node and connect it to rails. If it is possible where is a good place to start with.

Comment: http://faye.jcoglan.com/ this might be what you are looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create communication API between my website and my Client's website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964613/how-to-create-communication-api-between-my-website-and-my-clients-website)